# Why does Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.x not support Java (Maven) artefacts

Tags: nexus

The latest version of Nexus Repository Manager OSS supports a new artefact types: Docker, npm, RubyGems.  But it appears to *drop* support for artefact formats supported in the previous version: Maven, P2, OBR, Yum.  Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Maven should be there, in fact we setup default repos for it when it starts. P2, OBR, Yum have not been rebuilt for Nexus Repository Manager 3 as of yet. Yum will likely be the next up, P2 and then maybe OBR (jury is still out on if we have enough people using it to include it in the core product).

If you'd like to kickstart any of these, we would love that. A community member recently created an APT format for himself:

https://github.com/mpoindexter/nexus-repository-apt

You might be able to follow his example and create one for OBR for example.